# delayed_job - NameError - uninitilized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, nameerror

I have this custom job which is located in `/lib/jobs/MessageNotificationJob.rb`

```
class MessageNotificationJob < Struct.new(:user_id, :message_id)  

  def perform

        @user = User.find(user_id)
        @message = Message.find(message_id)
    if !message.reciever_open
        MessagesMailer.message_notification(@user, @message ).deliver

    end

  end
end
```

I call it from a method in the `MessagesController` with

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(MessageNotificationJob.new(@user.id, @msg.id))
```

In my `application.rb` I have

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

But I get the error

```
 NameError - uninitialized constant MessagesController::MessageNotificationJob:
```

How do I fix this? I've tried several variations, with this as the latest one as a solution to a similar question. I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the latest DelayedJob, but it looks an awful like the delayed job doesn't have the MessageNotificationJob class loaded when it runs.  Try the following:

```
# file: config/initializers/custom.rb
require 'message_notification_job'
```

See also [this wiki entry](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems#wiki-jobs_are_silently_removed_from_the_database) -- I think newer versions of DJ improved the error message (rather than silently failing), but the underlying cause is the same.

Comment: As I think about it, I'm pretty sure this is the problem.  The symbol reference comes from YAML.load() or equivalent, so simply adding MessageNotificationJob to the autoload list doesn't help.